# How to change Word 2013 thumbnails to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2013

As you can see in the below screenshot, if I hover over the advanced settings button, I get a thumbnail explaining the purpose of Paragraph Settings using the Windows XP UI.

[image: Thumbnail]

I am actually running Windows 7 and I was wondering how I can let Word 2013 know that I am using 7?

Comment: Word knows on which version of Windows is running. I think that the thumbnails are hard-coded screenshots and they look the same regardless the version of Windows the Word is running on. The question title is very confusing. Could you please change it for exmple to "How to change Word 2013 thumbnails to Windows 7 look?"

Comment: (On a side note: it seems odd that for a product named 2013 and with XP being close to be a discontinued product there are still traces of the Classic interface). ***If*** the images aren't hardcoded, then they could only be on the office folders; a search could yield them. Afterwards, a simple replacement would suffice.

Comment: Is this actually a problem? The contents of the dialog still looks the same, the only difference is the color of the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot indicates that you are running the add-in "Classic Menus for Office", with the sharp corners, "File" menu tab, etc., from http://www.addintools.com/office2010/word/

Disable the add-in and you can have the more modern look.

i.e.

[image: classic menus addin]